# Lua Get File Names in folder

Tags: lua

I am currently trying to figure out how to get all file names in a folder. (lua)

I already heave de folder name but i just need the files names.

Thanks in advance
Neo

Comment: not realy i need files from directory and if possibel if it end with .lua

Comment: Does `io.popen` work on your system?

Comment: I think thad it works but when i try is it gives my a empty table

Comment: which code gives you an empty table?  please add it to your question